# Swift Combine with Sync

Tags: swift, combine

I am new to combine.... I have a function that has a subscriber, and that function will return a value from the publisher, but the function will return an empty value before waiting for sink to complete.... is there a way I can wait for the sink and assign the value to the function return variable, then return the String back to the caller of this function.

```
 func getState() -> String{
    
    var state = ""
    let statesub = API.getCheckedState(employeeId: "342344", user: user!)
    statesub
        .mapError({ (error) -> APIError in // 5
            NSLog(error.errorDescription!)
            return error
        })
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in},
              receiveValue:{
                NSLog("State : \($0.state)")
                state = $0.state
              })
        .store(in: &tokens)
    return state
```

Comment: No, you can't. It's an async function, so if you never dealt with asynchronous programming, I strongly suggest you read up on that. In a nutshell, if you want the caller of the function to get the value, you need to either implement a callback (that the caller will provide) and call that inside the `.sink`, or if the caller expects a publisher, return the publisher (the chain before the `.sink`)

Answer (score 2):

In other programming languages, such as C#, there is the concept of `async/await`. You declare a part of your program as asynchronous by the keyword `async` and wait for the result with the `await` keyword in a non-blocking manner. However, this concept is not implemented in Swift (even tough it is heavily [discussed](https://gist.github.com/lattner/429b9070918248274f25b714dcfc7619)).

So, is there an alternative in Swift? Yes, using a [DispatchSemaphore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsemaphore). Your method should look like:

```swift
func getState() -> String {
    var state = ""
    var sema = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    let statesub = API.getCheckedState(employeeId: "342344", user: user!)
    statesub
        .mapError({ (error) -> APIError in // 5
            NSLog(error.errorDescription!)
            return error
        })
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in},
              receiveValue: {
                defer { sema.signal() }

                NSLog("State : \($0.state)")
                state = $0.state
              })
        .store(in: &tokens)

    sema.wait()
    return state
}
```

Comment: Async/await is now implemented in Swift 5.5 :-)

Comment: might be nice to update the swift proposal to https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0296-async-await.md